# Convert VarChar to Timestamp

Tags: mysql, varchar

I have 7 million rows of data within a MySQL table. One column of date-time data is in varchar format.

The data looks like this: `'2012-08-25 07:00:19 UTC'`

I want to convert this to be read as a timestamp in MySQL. I tried to change it with this code:

```
UPDATE `work_data`
SET `time_at` = str_to_date( `time_at`, '%Y-%m-%d $H:%i:%s'UTC)
```

It gives me Error code 1583.

Can anyone suggest an elegant way to convert this column of data with the table 'work data' to be timestamp instead of a varchar string?

Answer (score 2):

I changed your SQL. please check it once. what is the problem in your sql is $H. Just replace  `$H` to `%H`.

```
UPDATE work_data SET time_at = str_to_date( time_at, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
```

Thank you.

Comment: You satisfy my answer can you give a tick mark please.